# Entity Framework Automatic migrations that affect the location of the migrations history

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

My automatic migration keeps giving me this error when it tries to update the database.

> Automatic migrations that affect the location of the migrations
>   history system table (such as default schema changes) are not
>   supported. Please use code-based migrations for operations that affect
>   the location of the migrations history system table.

Here is my code:

```
[DbConfigurationType(typeof(AlvinCMSExtension.Migration.AlvinCMSCustomHistoryConfiguration))]
public class AccountDBContext : DbContext
{
    public AccountDBContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection")
    {
        Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<Alvin_CMS.Models.AccountDBContext, Alvin_CMS.Migrations.AccountDBContext.Configuration>());
    }

    public DbSet<UserProfile> UserProfiles { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Membership> Memberships { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Role> Roles { get; set; }
    public DbSet<UsersInRole> UsersInRoles { get; set; }
    public DbSet<OAuthMembership> OAuthMemberships { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ToString());
        string query = "select schema_name()";

        if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            con.Open();

        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(query, con);
        var x = com.ExecuteScalar();

        if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            con.Close();

        modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema(x.ToString());
    }
}

internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<Alvin_CMS.Models.AccountDBContext>
{
    public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
        MigrationsDirectory = @"Migrations\AccountDBContext";
        //SetHistoryContextFactory("System.Data.SqlClient", (conn, schema) => new AccountHistoryContext(conn, schema));
    }

    protected override void Seed(Alvin_CMS.Models.AccountDBContext context)
    {
        //  This method will be called after migrating to the latest version.

        //  You can use the DbSet<T>.AddOrUpdate() helper extension method 
        //  to avoid creating duplicate seed data. E.g.
        //
        //    context.People.AddOrUpdate(
        //      p => p.FullName,
        //      new Person { FullName = "Andrew Peters" },
        //      new Person { FullName = "Brice Lambson" },
        //      new Person { FullName = "Rowan Miller" }
        //    );
        //
    }
}

public class CustomHistoryContext : HistoryContext
{
    public CustomHistoryContext(DbConnection dbConnection, string defaultSchema)
        : base(dbConnection, defaultSchema)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("dbo");
        modelBuilder.Entity<HistoryRow>().ToTable(tableName: "__MigrationHistory", schemaName: "dbo");
        //modelBuilder.Entity<HistoryRow>().ToTable(tableName: "__MigrationHistory", schemaName: "dbo");
    }
}

public class AlvinCMSCustomHistoryConfiguration : DbConfiguration
{
    public AlvinCMSCustomHistoryConfiguration()
    {
        this.SetHistoryContext("System.Data.SqlClient",
            (connection, defaultSchema) => new CustomHistoryContext(connection, "dbo"));
    }
}
```

I can do the migration without any problem with the other DB Context, but only with this AccountDBContext the error always occurs. What is the cause of this error?

Comment: One bad solution will be to delete database and then apply migration if there is nothing important in DB.

Comment: I did this on the newly created database, the result is the same

Answer (score 5):

The error is because you have defined a custom schema name. If you want to use the custom schema name you can't use auto migrations. If you want to use auto migrations remove the call to `HasDefaultSchema` within `OnModelCreating`.

[Here is](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj591621(v=vs.113).aspx#Anchor_1) how you can enable Code First Migrations.